# How can I sort my month in the correct order in a pivot table?

Tags: apache-superset

Is there any way to sort the months in the correct order?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/goSHB.png)

I tried sorting them from SQL but superset does not want to cooperate

Answer (score 0):

Probably your month is a text column, not a date column. What I do in this cases is modify the text in the month column to allow a correct order: 01 - January, 02 - February....